# Kendo UI - Endless scroll won't work on GET twitter user_timeline

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-ui

I'm trying to get a user's timeline from twitter and display it in a list view. Currently I have a list view that displays the first 10 tweets in a user's timeline. However the endless scrolling feature doesn't work! No animation is shown when you get to the bottom of the page and no call to twitter is made via http request either (I have looked using wireshark). Below is my source code:

```
function loadTwitterFeed() {

var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json", // the remove service url
            dataType: "jsonp" // JSONP (JSON with padding) is required for cross-domain AJAX
        },
        parameterMap: function(options) {
            return {
                screen_name: "USER_NAME",
                count: 10,
                since_id: options.since_id, //additional parameters sent to the remote service
                max_id: options.max_id //additional parameters sent to the remove service
            };
        }
    }
});

$("#twitter-feed").kendoMobileListView({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    template: $("#twitter-template").text(),
    appendOnRefresh: true,
    pullToRefresh: true,
    //addition parameters which will be passed to the DataSource's read method
    pullParameters: function(item) { //pass first data item of the ListView
        return {
            since_id: item.id_str
        };
    },
    endlessScroll: true,
    //addition parameters which will be passed to the DataSource's next method
    endlessScrollParameters: function(firstOrigin) {
        if (firstOrigin) {
            return {
                max_id: firstOrigin.id_str
            };
        }
    }
});

}
```

It is similar to the twitter search demo but I have removed the serverPaging from the code as Twitter is getting rid of pages soon and is instead only using max_id and since_id. I've searched the documentation with no luck, it should work!

Does anybody know what's wrong?

Thanks,
Thomas

Link to twitter page on user_timeline: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Example Json request which works when copied and pasted into browser (just replace USER_NAME with valid one): http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=USER_NAME&count=10

Comment: Kendo UI documentation: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods    Kendo UI List view demo: http://demos.kendoui.com/mobile/listview/pull-with-endless.html

Comment: I somehow have a similar problem. I'm using the declarative html-binding (data-pull-to-refresh, etc). With these, the pullToRefresh and EndlessScroll things work. The Thing is: It seems that the internal page counter isn't reset when I pull to refresh. It refreshes Page #1 and when scrolling it loads page #2. So far correct. Then I pull again and it loads page #1. Scrolling now surprisingly doesn't load page #2 but page #3. After pulling again it's not possible to scroll anymore (since we're [internally] on the last page [3]). I just don't get it.